# Why Visual Studio doesn't add AspNetCompiler settings in solution file for configurations different from standard (Release/Debug)?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-automation, projects-and-solutions, aspnet-compiler

I have 3 build configurations for my solution: Release, Debug, and Custom. Also I have *WebSite* (yes, not a *WebApplication*) project type. By default, when you create WebSite VisualStudio 2008 adds to the solution file following sections:

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/MyWebSite"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MyWebSite\"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\MyWebSite\"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "false"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/MyWebSite"
Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MyWebSite\"
Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\MyWebSite\"
Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "false"
Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
SlnRelativePath = "\MyWebSite\"
```

This configuration is used by **MSBuild** to precompile/publish WebSite. As you can see here is no configuration for my **"Custom"** build configuration, only for **"Release"** and **"Debug"**. So when I am trying to build solution with MSBuild and with "Custom" build configuration WebSite simply don't get compiled.

But, when I manually add following lines in solution file everything works as expected. :

```
Custom.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/MyWebSite"
Custom.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MyWebSIte\"
Custom.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\MyWebSite\"
Custom.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "false"
Custom.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
Custom.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
Custom.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
```

I think that this is **a bug** in VisualStudio 2008 (I've checked this in 2010). The problem is that when VisualStudio 2008 will modify solution file (e.g. in case of adding a new project) my manually added lines will be removed. Maybe I should submit a bug somewhere to Microsoft VS development team?

If anyone else had the same problem and had any suggestions how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the "Custom" configuration to your project via the Configuration Manager dialog (under the Build > Configuration Manager menu item?)  It's possible that your manually-added section is incomplete, or there is another section in the solution file that VisualStudio expects to find modified as well.

Comment: I've already done this. Only AspNetCompiler settings were added manually.